# Error "No component for supporting the service Abp.MultiTenancy.ITenantIdResolver ..." when adding Asp.net boilerplate to an existing application

Tags: boilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate, aspnetboilerplate

I'm taking my first steps with Asp.net boilerplate.
I ran the sample projects fine.

Now, I'm trying to add Asp.net boilerplate to an existing application.
I haven't found a step by step tutorial to add Asp.net boilerplate capabilities to an existing application, so I just started by inheriting from AbpWebApplication instead of HttpApplication (like the samples do).

```
public class MvcApplication : AbpWebApplication
{
    protected override void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.Application_Start(sender, e);
    }
...
...
}
```

When I try to do this I get the error "*No component for supporting the service Abp.MultiTenancy.ITenantIdResolver was found*". See [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJSmp.png)
for complete callstack.

I tried installing Abp.Zero (even if I don't want a multitenant solution) to see if something changed, but I got the same message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in case someone is facing the same issue, I solved it overriding the method ResolveTenantIdOrNull of the class AbpWebApplication

```
    protected override int? ResolveTenantIdOrNull()
    {
        return null;
    }
```